# C++ Dynamic arrays of templated classes (i.e. vector)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I'm currently in the progress of teaching myself C++ and try to implement a simple hashmap (with two template classes ).

However, I can't figure out how to initialize a dynamic array of vectors correctly.
My attempts which have failed:

```
std::vector<Key> *keys = new std::vector<Key>[size];
std::vector<Key> *keys = (std::vector<Key> *) malloc(sizeof(std::vector<Key>) * size);
std::vector<Key> **keys = reinterpret_cast<vector<Key> **>(malloc(sizeof(vector<Key>) * size));
```

Or was I doing somewhere else something wrong? :(

Comment: `std::vector<Key> keys(size);`

Comment: Don't do that, just do `std::vector<std::vector<Key>>`.

Comment: I don't know where people get Malloc from.  I haven't used it since 1989.  Use New, but better than that, use std::make_shared<T> :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is unnecessary, vector supports dynamic sizing and you do not need to `new` it.

So:

```
std::vector<Key> keys = std::vector<Key>(size); // is fine to initialise the vector to a specific size.
```

if you want to have a pointer to a vector of  then you could new like so

```
std::vector<Key>* keys = new std::vector<Key>(size);
```

Also you can always add and remove elements on demand and it will resize if necessary or you can force it:

```
keys.resize(newSize); // note that if the new size is larger than current size
// it will default fill the new elements so if your `vector` is of `ints` 
// then it will pad with zeros.
```

Comment: You still have a new in there. `std::vector<Key> keys (size);` is enough. The new causes that one not to compile.

Comment: @chris yes I realised as soon as I posted so I corrected it, cheers

Comment: @EdChum.  The question is how to 'initialise' a dynamic array of vectors.  That isn't what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
std::vector<Key> *keys = new std::vector<Key>(size);
```

Even if one of those attempts worked:

```
std::vector<Key> *keys = (std::vector<Key> *) malloc(sizeof(std::vector<Key>) * size);
std::vector<Key> **keys = reinterpret_cast<vector<Key> **>(malloc(sizeof(vector<Key>) * size));
```

it would allocate memory, but not create object as it won't call its constructor.

Comment: I totally agree, but @rhue said that he is a C++ beginner, and this led me to conclusion that maybe he just wants to know how to create vector on heap.

Comment: Still good for people who come from Java to kick the unsafe C++ pointer habits that come with them. It's at least worth mentioning.